# Trying to solve the derivative of a given equation from the user using ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

As part of my AP computer science project, I decided to get a polynomial from a user and it will be able to find the derivative of the equation using the power rule.

For example, if the user enters `2X^3+5x^2` it should output `6x^2+10x^1`, so the coefficient and degree multiplied together and then the degree is just minus one. This is what I have so far but it's giving me a lot of errors, and tried following the code but don't see anything wrong with it. Thanks for your help.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        //input of polynomial 
        System.out.println("Enter polynomial:");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String polynomialEquation = sc.nextLine();

        //A string array list is created with the polynomial
        ArrayList<String> equationArr = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i<polynomialEquation.length(); i++) {
            equationArr.add(polynomialEquation.substring(i, i+1));
        }

        ArrayList<String> intStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

        //separate the numbers from the list

        for(int i =0; i<equationArr.size(); i++) {
            if (equationArr.get(i).equals("1") || equationArr.get(i).equals("2") || equationArr.get(i).equals("3") ||equationArr.get(i).equals("4") ||equationArr.get(i).equals("5") || 
            equationArr.get(i).equals("6") || equationArr.get(i).equals("7") || equationArr.get(i).equals("8") || equationArr.get(i).equals("9") || equationArr.get(i).equals("0"))
            {
                String addVal = equationArr.get(i);
                intStrings.add(addVal);
                equationArr.remove(i);  

            }
        }   


            //convert string integers to integers
        ArrayList<Integer> deriveInt  = new ArrayList<Integer>(intStrings.size());

        for (String myInt : intStrings) 
        { 
          deriveInt.add(Integer.valueOf(myInt)); 
        }


        //derive coefficiants 

        for (int i = 0; i<deriveInt.size()-1;i +=2) {

            deriveInt.set(i, deriveInt.get(i)*deriveInt.get(i+1));

        }

        //derive exponent

        for(int i = 1; i< deriveInt.size(); i +=2) {

            deriveInt.set(i,deriveInt.get(i)-1);        

        }

        //convert integer back to string
        ArrayList<String> stringDerive = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Integer myInt2 : deriveInt) 
        { 
          stringDerive.add(String.valueOf(myInt2)); 
        }

        //get the signs from the original equation

                ArrayList<String> sign = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i =0; i<equationArr.size(); i++) {

            if(equationArr.get(i).equals("+") || equationArr.get(i).equals("-")) {

                sign.add(equationArr.get(i));

            }
        }

        int totalSize = stringDerive.size() * 2 + equationArr.size();

        for (int i = 0; i<totalSize-1; i=+2) {

            int countSign= 0;

            System.out.print(stringDerive.get(i));
            System.out.print("x^");
            System.out.print(stringDerive.get(i+1));
            System.out.print(equationArr.get(countSign));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please inline your code properly.

Comment: 1. `totalSize` definitely greater than `stringDerive` length, this cause IndexOutOfBoundsException, 2. countSign is always 0

Comment: if you enter `2X^3+5x^2` then you separate its digits inside `deriveInt = [2, 3, 5, 2]`. Then you multiply coefficients and subtract exponents using the same array which contains all numbers. You have to multiply  coefficients `[2, 5]` and subtract exponents `[3, 2]` separately

Comment: Look up parsing methods. You'll probably want to parse the equation into expressions like `2X^3` and `5x^2`, rather than just putting all the tokens into lists.

Comment: Java is not a scrip language, divide your code into different methods (or even classes) based on responsibilities. This will not only make the code easier to read but it will be easier for you to visualize the logic and test and analyze your code.

Answer (score 1):

Polynomials are composed of monomials. In your example these are `2X^3` and `5x^2`. One of approach to solving your problem is writing the Monom class and Polynom class. I'll give you a skeleton so you can practice.

```
public class Helper {

        private class Monom{

            private int coefficient;
            private int degree;

            public Monom(int coefficient, int degree){
                this.coefficient = coefficient;
                this.degree = degree;
            }

            public Monom(String input){
                //TODO parse input. E.g Monom("6x^2) --> this.coefficient = 6...
                //TODO validate input
            }

            public Monom derivate(final Monom monom){
                return new Monom(monom.getCoefficient() * monom.getDegree(), monom.getDegree() - 1);
            }

            public int getCoefficient() {
                return coefficient;
            }

            public int getDegree() {
                return degree;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString(){
                return this.coefficient + "x^" + this.degree;
            }
        }

        //skeleton
        private class Polynom{

            private List<Monom> polynom; //holder of monoms
            //TODO rest of code including constructors, validate, derivate...

            public Polynom(List<Monom> monoms){
                this.polynom = monoms;
            }
            public Polynom derivate(Polynom input){
                List<Monom> temp = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Monom monom: polynom){
                    temp.add(monom.derivate(monom));
                }
                return new Polynom(temp);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            //TODO test code
            List<Monom> monoms = new ArrayList<>();
            //TODO rest of code like:
            // Polynom myPolynom = new Polynom(List<Monom> monoms);
            //...

        }

}
```

Like I said, this is just a code **you** have to upgrade... Good luck.

Comment: Another way to think about the problem: polynomials can be represented by a list of their coefficients. For example, -2x^3 + 5x^2 + 4 could be represented as (-2, 5, 0, 4). And the derivative would be (-6, 10, 0). Or they could easily be reversed as (4, 0, 5, -2) and (0, 10, -6). Think about the indexes... If you can massage the input into this format, it would be easier to work with.

Comment: @Floegipoky, I agree. That's why I said "One of approach". However, I think writing the small classes is the best way to maintenance any project. For example, in this case, the programmer could add many methods to classes Monom and Polynom: `"5x^2 + 2x^2 + 4x + 6"` reducing is `7x^2 + 4x + 6`. Nevertheless, your answer is good as well, so I'll give you +1. Cheers, friend

Comment: Thanks @zlakad, your approach would work much better for certain inputs that mine would fail miserably for. But I wanted to provide this idea because there's a good chance OP hasn't been exposed to OO design yet. I also think it emphasizes the underlying math a little more, at least for me.

Comment: @Floegipoky, thank you too, friend. Your code wouldn't fail at all. All whats needed is to validate input and transform it to proper list of coefficients (if possible, of course). OOP is the point when our mind has to be tuned for different kind of thinking (especially applied to me - I came from assembler coding... long time ago!). Good luck, pal.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Stack Overflow and the wonderful world of programming! On a personal note, I started coding in high school with APCS too :)

Your question is arguably a bit too broad for this site. For example, you mentioned the code is "giving me a lot of errors": a better question would include the inputs you've tried and the specific output you're seeing and what you expected instead. I still want to help you though, so I'll give you some feedback and we can work through a few revisions.

First, I see that you've divided your program into sections using comments. This is a great instinct! You've decomposed the larger problem into smaller problems in a way that communicates your intent.

1. input of polynomial
2. A string array list is created with the polynomial
3. separate the numbers from the list
4. convert string integers to integers
5. derive coefficiants
6. derive exponent
7. convert integer back to string
8. get the signs from the original equation

However, it still leaves us with the problem of having a large `main` method to understand. So for your next revision, you should fix that by breaking it up into smaller methods. You can start by moving each of these "steps" into its own method, then call each of them from `main`. To help you get started, here's what it would look like with your first "step" extracted:

```
public class Practice {
    public static String readPolynomial() {
        System.out.println("Enter polynomial:");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String polynomialEquation = sc.nextLine();
        return polynomialEquation;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String polynomialEquation = readPolynomial();

        //A string array list is created with the polynomial
        ...
    }
}
```

I think you'll find that this really improves your understanding of both your code and the problem you're trying to solve. Don't be afraid to change the steps based on that new understanding. It's no coincidence that the buggy or unfocused areas of your code are the areas you'll struggle the most to name. Try to focus on the problem, rather than your implementation. For instance, my first step would probably be a combination of your first few. Things like parsing the input String and then converting from Strings to Integer don't have much to do with polynomials or derivatives. So for `readPolynomial` I would prefer:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> readPolynomial() {
```

The other big benefit of this refactor is that it will be much easier for you to test that each step is working the way you want it to. It gives you much more fine-grained control because you can test each method individually, rather than only being able to test by running the entire program. It will be much easier to isolate, understand, and fix each individual bug.

Another big thing: please provide some more sample inputs! Not only will this help clarify requirements, but we can use them as test cases later.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response it was nice to hear from a former AP comp sci student! I agree with all your points on creating methods to better organize the code and possibly identify the problem easier. I have figured out a couple of problems by adding a few lines of code and changing somethings up But im now at the point were i have to figure out how to print the output at the end as a for-loop is not working to well. But again thank you for your response and I have just begun this journey into what I hope will become my career in the future

Comment: UPDATE: I just figured out the program and can now make it work for as many terms as possible. My next step is to try and do the calculations when the coefficient and degree are greater than 9. Or when the derivative of the exponent is x^0 then it just cancels out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's some functioning code to help you, please don't just take it for granted but read it and understand what is happening. If you have any questions on it please ask. It could use some cleanup but hopefully it's still understandable.

One minor thing to note is that sign is attached to the expressions (as it kinda should be) so you could just `+` all the expressions together and it would be valid. But if you want to avoid having an answer like `6x^2 + -10y^4` and would rather have `6x^2 - 10y^4` then you'd have to check if the expressions are negative when building the answer with them.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // input requires all constants to be fully resolved
        // eg. no '3^2^1^3', instead it should be '9'
        // eg. no '5*2x', instead it should be '10x'

        // mess around with the input to test
        String s = "2x^3+5x^2";

        List<DerivableExpression> list = parseDeriveableExpressions(s);

        List<DerivableExpression> derivatives = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DerivableExpression de : list)
            derivatives.add(de.getDerivative());

        System.out.println(String.join("+", derivatives)); // 6x^2+10x^1
    }

    private static List<DerivableExpression> parseDeriveableExpressions(String s) {
        // remove all spaces and lowercase everything
        s = s.replace(" ", "");

        List<DerivableExpression> list = new ArrayList<>();
        char var = ' ';
        StringBuilder constBuff = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder powerBuff = new StringBuilder();
        boolean parsingPower = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (c == '+' || c == '-') {
                if (parsingPower && powerBuff.length() == 0) {
                    // at the start of the power expression
                    if (c == '-')
                        powerBuff.append(c);
                } else {
                    // either not parsing a power or not at the start of the power
                    // this is a +/- after the power, terminating the expression
                    parsingPower = false;
                    int constant = 1;
                    if (constBuff.length() > 0) {
                        constant = Integer.parseInt(constBuff.toString());
                        constBuff.setLength(0);
                    }
                    if (var != ' ' && constant != 0) {
                        int power = 1;
                        if (powerBuff.length() > 0) 
                            power = Integer.parseInt(powerBuff.toString());
                        list.add(new VariableExpression(constant, var, power));
                    } else {
                        list.add(new ConstantExpression(constant));
                    }
                    powerBuff.setLength(0);
                    var = ' ';
                    // append the sign for the next expression
                    if (c == '-')
                        constBuff.append(c);
                }
            } else if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') {
                if (parsingPower)
                    powerBuff.append(c);
                else
                    constBuff.append(c);
            } else if (('a' <= c && c <= 'z') || ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')) {
                if (constBuff.length() == 0 ||
                        (constBuff.length() == 1 && constBuff.charAt(0) == '-'))
                    constBuff.append("1");
                var = c;
            } else if (c == '^') {
                parsingPower = true;
            }
        }

        // add the last expression
        int constant = 1;
        if (constBuff.length() > 0) {
            constant = Integer.parseInt(constBuff.toString());
            constBuff.setLength(0);
        }
        if (var != ' ') {
            int power = 1;
            if (powerBuff.length() > 0) {
                power = Integer.parseInt(powerBuff.toString());
                powerBuff.setLength(0);
            }
            list.add(new VariableExpression(constant, var, power));
            var = ' ';
        } else {
            list.add(new ConstantExpression(constant));
        }

        return list;
    }

    private static interface DerivableExpression {
        public abstract DerivableExpression getDerivative();

    }

    private static class VariableExpression implements DerivableExpression {
        private final int constant;
        private final char variable;
        private final int power;
        public VariableExpression(int constant, char variable, int power) {
            this.constant = constant;
            this.variable = variable;
            this.power = power;
        }

        @Override public VariableExpression getDerivative() {
            return new VariableExpression(constant * power, variable, power - 1);
        }
        @Override public String toString() { return constant + "" + variable + "^" + power; }
    }

    private static class ConstantExpression implements DerivableExpression {
        private final int constant;
        public ConstantExpression(int constant) {
            this.constant = constant;
        }

        @Override public DerivableExpression getDerivative() { return this; }
        @Override public String toString() { return Integer.toString(constant); }
    }
}
```